# How to apply multi conditions in FILTER in Google Sheets?

Tags: filter, google-sheets

**Target**: Check which **ROWs** contain YTD but No Name inputted

```
# DT
  A    B     C    D
1 IND  NAME  YTD  RF  
2 AA   Paul   27  56
3 AA          12  7
4 BB   Tom    14  18
5 BB           4  
6 CC   Sue    51  42
7 CC   Mary    1   4
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
3
5
```

**MY Formula**:

```
=filter(ROW(A2:A27),AND(ISBLANK(B2:B7),C2:C7<>0))
```

but error return:

> FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 5. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1

Multi conditions for filter

```
AND(ISBLANK(B2:B7),C2:C7<>0)
```

Expect to return the value of sheet ROW number

```
ROW(A2:A7)
```

It is works when check which rows RF value bigger than YTD:

```
=filter(ROW(B2:B7),B2:B7>D2:D7)
# RESULT
3
5
```

**How can I achieve the target?**

Comment: Solved with remove AND() functions

Answer (score 1):

you need to drop `AND` coz you dealing with array

```
=FILTER(ROW(A2:A), ISBLANK(B2:B), C2:C<>0)
```

[image: 0]